# Bind events to dynamically added elements

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to bind functions to newly added elements using jquery...I have tried numerous examples online, but somehow nothing works for me. I created a form with id and a button, on submit ajax loads elements from another page and inserts the html on current website. Everything seems to work fine, but the newly loaded elements don't have any events binded on.
Here is the html:

```
<form id="tclick" method="post" action="${tg.url('/entryCmd')}">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${entries[0].id}"  />
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

and jQuery:

```
$("#tclick").on("submit", function(data){
    var h = $(this).serialize();
    var d;

    $.get($(this).attr("action"), h, 
        function(returnData) {
            d = returnData;
        }
    );

    $(this).ajaxStop(function(){
        $(this).after($(d).find(".edit-content").html());
    });

    return false;
});
```

The edit-content div gets loaded right after the form element. It has some a elements, that sould be bound to jQuery functions.

Comment: @jack-all-trades `live` is deprecated in favor of `on`, see http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: @jack-all-trades. And he is not using .live() anyway

Answer (score 4):

Got basically two options to do this:

1. Bind your events after appending the new html:

   ```
   $(this).ajaxStop(function(){
        $(this).after($(d).find(".edit-content").html());
        // do you binding here
   });
   ```
2. Use event delegation (with [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)).

   ```
   $('.some-container').on('click', '.edit-button', function(e) {...});
   ```

   This will delegate the click event to an element .some-container for any children with class .edit-button, not matter the latter was already in the dom or loaded afterwards.

Comment: I've tryed this, but if I put in the '.edit-button' parameter in the on function, the site gets refreshed, if I delete it, the elements get loaded without refresh.

Comment: Honestly i'm not sure to understand. I don't see how the page can get refreshed because of the .on(), makes no sense. Can you edit your question with your changed code to have a bigger picture on you do it ?

Comment: OK, I got it now, I was using on only for #tclick, I changed all events to on(click, function(){...}) and rebinded them, its working now...I still dont understand exactly how jquery works, only learning through tutorials...I should read a book about jquery some day:P

Comment: I'm not a guru and I still learn from it but it's a bit easier when you have the basics. Note that you don't have to use .on() for everything. For static elements, just use .bind() to bind events, not need to delegate.

Answer (score 1):

To add events to elements which are added to the DOM after page load you need to use either `delegate()`, or if you're using jQuery 1.7+ `on()`.

```
$(".edit-content").delegate("#myDiv", "click", function() {
    // do stuff when #myDiv gets clicked.
});
```

API:
[Delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)
[On](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: I am using on, but somehow it does not work for me...what am I doing wrong? :/