# jquery .on click not working with later added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following issue. As far as I know, using .on function should add event listeners to selected elements even though they might not exists at the present time. I am replacing elements on my page and after they are replaced, event listeners are not attached to them.
So where did I make mistake?

Here is the code which is not working:

html:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>item1</li>
        <li>item2</li>
        <li>item3</li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<button>change</button>
```

javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $("ul li").on("click", function() {
        $(this).css({"color": "red"});
    });

    $("button").on("click", function() {
        $("ul li").css({"color": "black"});

        var html = $("nav").html();
        $("nav").html(html);
    });
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q48db/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bind events to dynamically added elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8805689/bind-events-to-dynamically-added-elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) will not make an event handler to work on dynamic elements, you need to use the [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) format of `on()`

The format for event delegation is

```
$(static-ancestor).on(event, dynamic-element-selector, handler)
```

So

```
$("nav").on("click", 'li', function () {
    $(this).css({
        "color": "red"
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/n5hQf/)

In your case the `nav` element is the static element because you are changing the its content so you can bind the handler to it and since you want to have the click handler for the `li` elements pass `li` as the dynamic element selector

Comment: @MatúšDúbrava see the update... it should have been `$('nav').on(...)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **[event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** for dynamically added element:

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all children matching a selector,
>   whether those children exist now or are added in the future.

```
$(function () {
    $("nav").on("click", 'li', function () {
        $(this).css({
            "color": "red"
        });
    });

    $("button").on("click", function () {
        $("ul li").css({
            "color": "black"
        });
        var html = $("nav").html();
        $("nav").html(html);
    });
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q48db/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use [event Delegation method](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

```
$(function() {
    $("ul li").on("click", function() {
        $(this).css({"color": "red"});
    });

    $("document").on("click","button", function() {
        $("ul li").css({"color": "black"});

        var html = $("nav").html();
        $("nav").html(html);
    });
});
```

---

Example to understand event delegation:

```
// attach a directly bound event
$( "#list a" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
console.log( $( this ).text() );
});

// attach a delegated event
$( "#list" ).on( "click", "a", function( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
console.log( $( this ).text() );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need delegate.

```
$("nav").on("click",'ul li', function() {
    $(this).css({"color": "red"});
});

$("button").on("click", function() {
    $("ul li").css({"color": "black"});
                    
    var html = $("nav").html();
    $("nav").html(html);
});
```

[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q48db/2/)